# change date process maker to persian date ( jalali ) or add date picker jalali

Tags: date, calendar, date-format, processmaker

I want to change dates shown everywhere in processmaker to another format(Persian calendar). I have my custom class to format dates. What is the best way to override the default function which returns the formatted date? I just found the CurDate method in the G class. Changed it's returned value but dates are still shown in gregorian format. Is there any other method for formatting dates?

I prefer an OOP solution to override the default function instead of hacking the core, if possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://processmakerplus.com/

**For daynaform in PM2.x**

1.Add  `jalali.js`([Download](http://ashkufaraz.persiangig.com/other/pcal.rar/dl)) file to path `\opt\processmaker\gulliver\js\widgets\pcal`

2.Change the maborak file in path `\processmaker\gulliver\js\maborak\core\maborak.js` changed setup calendar  like this

```
 Calendar.setup({
        inputField: id,
        ifFormat: mask,
        dateType: 'jalali',
        button: id + "[btn]",
        bottomBar: true,
        showsTime: showTIme,
        opacity: 1,
    });
```

[maborak.js](http://ashkufaraz.persiangig.com/other/maborak.js)

3.In path`\processmaker\gulliver\system\class.headPublisher.php` and in `function printHeader ()` you must add jalali.js file to header dynaform like this 
`$this->addScriptFile("/js/widgets/pcal/jalali.js");`[class.publisher.php](http://ashkufaraz.persiangig.com/other/class.publisher.php/dl)

**For other place** like current date top of the home page must in path `processmaker\workflow\engine\skinEngine\skinEngine.php` and in `function _default()` replace

`$smarty->assign('udate', G::getformatedDate(date('Y-m-d'), 'M d, yyyy', SYS_LANG))` with

```
include_once("includes/inc.jdf.php");
$smarty->assign('udate', jdate('d F Y'));
```

**For dynaform in PM 3.x**

1.Add bootstrap date picker file([Download](http://ashkufaraz.persiangig.com/other/jalali.rar/dl)) to path `processmaker\workflow\public_html\lib\pmdynaform\libs\datepicker\jalali`

2.Add address this file to external lib

`/lib/pmdynaform/libs/datepicker/jalali/bootstrap-datepicker.js,/lib/pmdynaform/libs/datepicker/jalali/bootstrap-datepicker.css,/lib/pmdynaform/libs/datepicker/jalali/bootstrap-datepicker.fa.js`

3.Add input(`id=txt_dateSabt`) to dynaform and create data picker with this java script code `$("#txt_dateSabt").find("input").datepicker();`

[Sample dynaform with jalali date picker](http://ashkufaraz.persiangig.com/other/DynaformWithJalaliDate.json)
[image]
[image]

Comment: thanks for your great answer. 3rd part is so myth can you explain in details please? :)

Comment: what is your mean?

Comment: how can make standard form element for persian date in Dyna form builder?

Comment: no changes occured in my case. part 3 in console just return an object!